# How to group array 1 dimensional to array 2 dimensional?

Tags: php, arrays

My array one is like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total_transaction] => 2000000
            [month] => May
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total_transaction] => 1000000
            [month] => June
        )
)
```

My array two is like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4000000
    [1] => 5000000
)
```

I want to group the array like this :

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [target] => 4000000
                [total_transaction] => 2000000
                [month] => May
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [target] => 5000000
                [total_transaction] => 1000000
                [month] => June
            )
    )
```

I'm still confused

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `array_map` and `array_replace_recursive` functions:

```
// $arrOne is your first array
$arrTwo = [4000000, 5000000];  // it's your second array

$arrTwo = array_map(function($v){ return ['target' => $v]; }, $arrTwo);
$result = array_replace_recursive($arrOne, $arrTwo);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total_transaction] => 2000000
            [month] => May
            [target] => 4000000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total_transaction] => 1000000
            [month] => June
            [target] => 5000000
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
foreach($array1 as $key1=>$arr1) {
   if(isset($array2[$key1])) $array1[$key1]['target'] = $array2[$key1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            "total_transaction" => 2000000,
            "month" => "May"
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            "total_transaction" => 1000000,
            "month" => "June"
        )
);

$b = array
(
    0 => 4000000,
    1 => 5000000
);

foreach($a as $key=>$val) {
   $a[$key]['target'] = $b[$key];
}
```

Try this one..

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$out = array();
foreach ($aa1 as $key => $value){
    $out[] = (object)array_merge((array)$aa2[$key], (array)$value);
}
print_r($out);
```

https://3v4l.org/kBJVB

i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array(
    array(
        'total_transaction' => 2000000,
        'month' => 'May'
    ),
    array(
        'total_transaction' => 1000000,
        'month' => 'June'
    ));

$array2 = array(
'0' => 4000000,
'1' => 5000000
);

foreach($array2 as $k=>$v){
    $array1["$k"]['target']=$v;
}
```